# How to get singly linked list node value from pointer to pointer of that node?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I want to remove node from singly linked list. I have variable 'pp' (pointer to pointer of the current node) which traverses whole list until it finds node to remove (in that case, node with value 'a'), but when I'm trying to reach the value of the current node it gives me an error (left of '->value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type) Please tell me what's wrong with my code

```
Node** pp = &head;
while(*pp->value != a){ \\ error on this line
    pp = &(*pp->next);
}
*pp = *pp->next;
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please read [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Saba! When asking about why your code is not working, you should provide a Minimal Complete Verified Example (MCVE). Read on how-to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Saba, don't forget to `free` the node to be deleted, after updating the `next` pointer, as I mentioned in my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using parentheses, like this:

```
(*pp)->value
```

since [operators precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) results in the error your facing. The operator `->` has higher precedence than the operator `*`, that's why you need to use parentheses.

The error (left of '->value' must point to class/struct/union/generic type) hints you strongly for what happened here: You attempted to ask for `value` in something not a structure, you attempted to ask for a member in an address (`pp`), and not in a struct (where `pp` points to, i.e. `*pp`).

Don't forget to use parentheses in the rest of your code, like this `(*pp)->next`.

PS: Don't forget to `free` the node to be deleted, *after* you have updated the `next` pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis around *pp, needed due to operator precedence

```
Node** pp = &head;
while((*pp)->value != a){ \\ error on this line
    pp = &((*pp)->next);
}
*pp = (*pp)->next;
```